# Does Landsat satellite image should have raster value to -1 and 1?

Tags: arcmap, remote-sensing, ndvi, classification, image

I am calculating the NDVI for Landsat-8 using the formula as shown below:-
[image]

But the pixel value rendered is as shown below: -
[image]

But the NDVI values need to be between -1 and +1 however, the value rendered is between 114085 and 9822.95. These values when scaled to 100000 gives value between:- 1.1 and 0.09. How can these be solved?

Comment: You did your math incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Order of operations means your division is occurring first. Put brackets around your addition and subtraction.

```
(Float(NIR) - Red) / (Float(NIR) + Red)
```

I dropped the 2nd and last `Float` calls as they're not required because the NIR values are already cast to floating point so the whole operation is promoted.

Comment: I used the formula as:- (Float("LC09_L1TP_140041_20220213_20230427_02_T1_B5.TIF")-("LC09_L1TP_140041_20220213_20230427_02_T1_B4.TIF"))/(Float("LC09_L1TP_140041_20220213_20230427_02_T1_B5.TIF")+ ("LC09_L1TP_140041_20220213_20230427_02_T1_B4.TIF"))  and the NDVI value rendered is between : -0.42 to 0.54 . Is that Okay? Or it must rendered value between -1 and +1.

Comment: That *is* between -1 and +1, it might well be ok that your  min and max values are not reaching the limits

Comment: @bugmenot123 What actually cause this???

Comment: Do you understand the formula you are using? Maybe pick the values of one pixel and calculate the index manually

Comment: @bugmenot123 NDVI values can be between -1 and 1 theoretically, it just happens that in my image min/max pixel values are -0.43 and 0.54. So, this should be right as per my understanding.

Comment: I understand it the same way :)